# Optimization Problem: Minimize the absolute value of a set of points

Tags: optimization

I have the following optimization problem:

Given is a set of $n$ points $x_i, \ldots, x_n$ with $x_i \in \mathbb{C}, \|x_i\| < \infty$. Note that $n$ is usually not large, i.e. $n < 1000$. We want to find a point $c \in \mathbb{C}$ such that

$\max_i \| x_i + c \|$ is minimized

Currently, this problem is solved by means of an iterative descent algorithm:

1. Initialize $c^{(0)} = 0$
2. For $j = 0, \ldots, j_\mathrm
   {iter}$

   21. Find $\max_i \| x_i + c^{(j)} \|$
   22. Set $c^{(j+1)} = c^{(j)} - \alpha \frac{x_i + c^{(j)}}{\| x_i + c^{(j)} \|}$
       ,where $\alpha$ is some stepwidth.

This algorithm works fine, but: I am looking for another (faster) solution. I wonder if it is possible to use any non-iterative solver. So far, I couldn't come up with any. So do you have any ideas how to tackle this?
Thanks

Comment: If you instead search for $c'  = -c$, you get a more standard distance functional $\|x_i - c'\|$. This should make geometric considerations simpler.

Comment: My intuition says that you should then consider the convex hull of your points, but one would have to work out if that's sufficient.

Comment: If you are going to iteratively solve it, initialize it at the center of the range of the data.

Comment: I agree that you can ignore all points that are not on the convex hull. That should reduce the number of points you need to consider significantly.

Comment: Also, the problem will turn into a simple linear programming problem if you allow yourself the use of the $l_1$ norm instead of the Euclidean norm.